# Save file from url base64 data to pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, fs

I am making a react app where I have a field that allows users to upload PDF files.

I have successfuly uploaded and sent the files as base64 string to the server and I do receive it, however I am having trouble with saving the file back to pdf, here is what I have tried:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const invoice = { fileData: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjandtherestofthedatastring..." };

const invoiceFileContents = new Buffer.from(invoice.fileData, "base64");
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "invoicetest.pdf", invoiceFileContents);
```

This does create a pdf file, but I am unable to open it, Adobe says its broken.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, the appended string infront of the whole data string `data:application/pdf;base64,` should be trimmed:

```
const invoiceFileContents = new Buffer.from(
    invoice.fileData.substring(invoice.fileData.indexOf("base64") + 7),
    "base64"
  );
```